# I am trying to make the swipeable tab layout in android but getting null value in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

I am trying to make the two tab layout for {profile} and {Child} which should be swipeable too. I have created the layout and fragment for both of them and on Main Activity layout, I have put

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

And in my Main Activity.java class my code is

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = {"Profile", "Child"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    actionBar = (ActionBar) getSupportActionBar();

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

But here in actionBar, I am getting null value, so program execute with null pointer at that point. Due to what reason, null might be coming in getActionBar.

Comment: I have tried with actionBar = getActionBar(); this also. But same result with null pointer exception.

Comment: What theme does your activity have?

Comment: Which theme you are using for the activity? If you use like 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar', you need to add Toolbar to layout.

Comment: I am using android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar". Now what i need to do to make it working?

Comment: Hi Onur Taskin, in my manifest, theme is : android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" and my xml layout have <RelativeLayout inside this there is <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. What toolbar should i need to add here.

Comment: Check this out : http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/android-toolbar-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your activity theme to `@style/Theme.AppCompat` **or** define toolbar in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
         android:id="@+id/pager"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And set custom action bar:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    actionBar = (ActionBar) getSupportActionBar();
}
```

`ActionBar` tabs is deprecated and not working since API 21. You should use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library.

Comment: Hi Mixel, I tried this     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        // Initialization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     //   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = (ActionBar) getSupportActionBar(toolbar); But saying "can't resolved getSupportActionBar"

Comment: By `Toolbar` do you mean `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` or `android.widget.Toolbar`? You have to use first.

Comment: Hi Mixel, I have used android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: You should call `getSupportActionBar()` without parameter as in my answer.

Comment: @ mixel :I have used `
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = getActionBar();` where i am making mistake. because still I am getting null in actionBar

Comment: You should call `getSupportActionBar()` not `getActionBar()` because you are using support library. Please read carefully my answer.

Comment: your solution solved that issue but all this i have doing to make swipeable tab layout so in this code **viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);** **Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);** **setSupportActionBar(toolbar);** **actionBar = (ActionBar) getSupportActionBar();** **mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());** **viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);** **actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);** **actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);** 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tabs not supported in this configuration**

Comment: 'ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` is deprecated and does not work since API 21. Please use https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. that solved my issue.